# Twilio Phone Number- In "Properties" there is no "City, State"

Tags: twilio

We purchased a number from Twilio. 480 area code. Phoenix location.
Our client reports that when she views the call reports, the calls are all in Eastern Time. She's on Pacific Time (Arizona is either MST or Pacific)

When I view the "properties" of the phone number we purchased, it says in the "location" section: NA

Most of our other numbers show a city/state. (which in turn reports the calls in the correct time zones)

Is there a way to change the properties of this number, or is there a way to ask Twilio to change the properties of this number to show Phoenix, AZ instead of NA?

Thanks in advance,
Valerie VanBooven

Comment: Hey Valerie, Twilio developer evangelist here. If you get in touch with help@twilio.com, they will be able to look into that for you. HTH

Comment: Thank you, I did submit a support ticket, but it goes unanswered.